# Jquery print pdf contained in a string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I'm having some problems in the printing of a pdf.
Using the following AJAX (that goes well, without any error) I retrive a string from `print_invitee.php`, passing some data `("data_e")`, that contains a pdf made from an HTML.

My question is: how can I open the print window option with the content of "data" only using jQuery?

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    url : "print_invitee.php",
    data : data_e,
    success : function(data) {
        if (data) {
            console.log(data.valueOf());
        }
    }
});
```

print_invitee.php:

```
function create_pdf_ricevuta_invitee(...*somecorrectparams*...) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
    $content = **...contentinhtml...**;
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','it');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $content_PDF = $html2pdf->Output('', true);
    return $content_PDF;
}
echo create_pdf_ricevuta_inviter(...*somecorrectparams*...);
```

As you probably noticed I'm using *http://html2pdf.fr/*.

EDIT (add from comments):
*I'm on a server in which I can't create N pdf files*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create PDF file and return link of that. Then you will get a link in ajax and handle it as you like (show PDF or link to PDF):

```
$content_PDF = $html2pdf->Output('exemple.pdf');
```

Comment: I tried.. but that doesn't solved my problem.
As you may guess, $content_pdf continues to contatin the string rapresentation of the pdf, and not the link to ('example.pdf'). Also, I'm on a server in which I can't create N pdf files.
But thank you anyway

Comment: @elab I think he's saying, create the pdf, save it as a file on the server, and then return a link to that file. Which isn't a bad plan even if you have to delete the file after using it